# How do Star Wars bounty hunters fulfill criminal and government contracts?

Tags: star-wars, bounty-hunters

It seems like just about anyone can put out a bounty on someone in Star Wars. Jabba the Hutt is fond of putting them out on people. Jabba is a crime lord, so these might more appropriately be called "hits", not bounties.

Bounty Hunters also seem to work for government, as evidenced by being hired by Darth Vader to track down the Millenium Falcon. But if most of the contracts they do are extra-legal, shouldn't they be considered criminals and get arrested by the Empire? Or does declaring yourself a bounty hunter make you somehow immune to the rule of law?

The real-world equivalent would be if like Dog the Bounty Hunter tracked down people for Los Zetas and the US Government knew about it and also hired him to track down enemies of the state, which makes no sense.

Comment: Why are you assuming that this does NOT indeed happen as your last paragraph says, in many countries?

Comment: Also, Xisor was Emperor's buddy. Being a criminal in the Empire != being arrested.

Comment: Being a bounty hunter was legal, the guilds were established upon the suggestion of the Galactic Senate so that they could police themselves. If you committed crimes as a bounty hunter then that is what made you a criminal. Cad Bane was considered a criminal because he committed crimes against the Republic and on various planets, not just because he was a bounty hunter. Also, considering some of the jobs that the Empire hired bounty hunters to perform, I doubt they were excessively concerned with legality, so much as utility.

Answer (score 7):

**Answer: Hunting bounties is perfectly legal if you have the documentation and obey the rules.**

To be a legal bounty hunter you need to be a member of the [Bounty Hunter's Guild](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_Hunters'_Guild) and apply for an [Imperial Peace-Keeping Certificate](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Peace_Keeping_Certificate). Failure to do so will only net you half the reward you'd otherwise get for a bounty. You'd expect punishment to be more severe, but that's it. There are a number of rules when hunting bounties though:

- First, unless the bounty was posted as "Dead or Alive", it was to be captured alive.
- Second, the quarry must be given the chance to surrender. However, "flight, refusal to comply with the directives of a registered hunter, prior activities indicating a predisposition to resistance to capture, resistance, or assault" is considered refusal to surrender.
- Third, injury, incapacitation or death of the quarry may only occur if the quarry has refused to surrender peacefully, however, the same exceptions that apply to the second rule also apply to this one.
- Fourth, only a reasonable amount of force is to be used.
- Fifth, the holder of the IPKC must promise not to accept any "illegal" bounties.

(Note that the information on the IPKC comes from the West End Games RPG, so take it with whatever grain of salt you want.)

Of course, not everyone works this way. Criminal elements don't like regulation, and as such work outside the law when dealing with non-Empire entities like the Hutts. Boba Fett didn't like the guild at all so he destroyed it, leaving only the bounty hunters you see in Episode V alive.

So yes, bounty hunting is perfectly legal, as long as you sign up with the guild and play by the rules.

Comment: [IPKCs themselves appear to enjoy canon support](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Peace-Keeping_Certificate/Canon), although the rules are Legends. +1

Comment: these rules seem to be similar in the case of bounty hunters in the starwars mmo, essentially hunters are part of an organization, and take legally sanctioned bounties from government officials. not to mention in reality, bounty hunters are also perfectly legal.

Comment: @DVK Indeed, I fixed that part.

Comment: @Himarm As far as I know it's only legal in the US, and then not even in all states. Additionally there's no such thing as private sector bounties so I don't think it's current legal status is very relevant to the Star Wars model.